# CGContext errors in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

When I run my application it works well, but during transitions between its views I have a lot of CGContext errors in the console output, but the app still works well, no crashes or bugs I didn't see.

Description:  so I only run my app - all work well - but there appears error messages in the console:
[image]

And after any other view transition they appear again and again. So the question - how to fix this? And what may be the reason of this error messages? There a lot of views and code in my application so I don't even know what part is error-prone.But these messages appear after transitions between all views in my app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging a NULL CGContext under Cocoa/Carbon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876017/debugging-a-null-cgcontext-under-cocoa-carbon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for some method in your code where you call CGContextSaveGState, CGContextSetBlendMode, CGContextSetApha, etc. Chances are that you won´t find many places where you do that.

Well, if you find it, look for some statement (just before those listed in your console log) where a context is created, and try to understand why it fails. You may set a breakpoint on that line and inspect the parameters to the `CGContextCreate` call.

If you need more help, paste the code you have (hopefully) found.